# Any advice to store username/password or token for Auto-login page iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cookies, web-storage

I'm looking for how to remember username/password or token for auto-login WIFI login page.
Is that safari disallowed to use Cookies/Web storage?

Can anybody suggest me how to store data in web clients iOS safari for an appeared WIFI login page.

First, I tried to use Cookies. It's working to Safari, but auto-login Safari popup is not working.
HTML5 Web Storage is exactly problem.

Comment: Don't store passwords in cookies would be the first thing.

Comment: I agree with you, but we have to meet customer requirement for an easy to use reason.

Comment: safari give user option to store user data you dont need to

Comment: I have tried with JavaScript technical such jquery cookies/ HTML5 Web Storage. It's worked with normally Safari but auto-login wifi page(Captive portal).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do auto login use users token. like facebook authentication you stay login for some time period. how ever i consider your WIFI login system authentication from a web server so you can generate token for users . and those tokens you can keep in cookies.

Comment: Cookies is the first choice to try.
Cookies is not work for auto-login popup iOS. It only work for safari browsers normally usage.